# How to synchronize multiple Background services (.Net 6 ) during initialization step?

Tags: synchronization, .net-6.0, worker

I have two Workers in my .net6 project like below:

```
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker1>();
        services.AddHostedService<Worker2>();

    }).Build();
```

how can I make sure Worker2 start after only Worker1 has started? It is possible in this scenario?

Comment: What do you mean precisely when you say 'has started'?

Comment: I mean that "StartAsync" of Worker1 has finished (initialization finished), so "StartAsync" of Worker2 can start its initialization which depend on the some variables which are initialized in Worker1's StartAsync

Comment: Don't know if this is a good practice. Why not initialize the variables before you add the workers? If those variables are not constants and you need to run Worker2 after Worker1, then you can just merge the workers or use events like `RunWorkerCompleted`